# MacBook uploading data over the Internet on Wi-Fi connection

Tags: data-transfer, internet

I can see upload traffic to the internet being generated by a MacBook once it connects to our LAN. The owner states he's not using iCloud and doesn't know why this occurs.

I am not a Mac expert but I may give it go to fix the issue.

What should I check for, apart from viruses? Is there a well known functionality in Macs once they connect to the Internet?

Answer (score 2):

### Activity Monitor

To see the number of sent packages you can use "Activity Monitor".

Open it and choose the "Network" tab. Click the "Sent Bytes" column to sort all applications by data sent.

---

### Little Snitch

You can use a firewall software like "[Little Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html)" to monitor any incoming and outgoing network connections. It can display a detailed traffic history which you can filter by application.

It is a paid software but you can use the trial for a few days and remove it afterwards.

Keep in mind that this requires you to install the software on the client's machine.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Are you aware about default mac software that could try to synch something upon connection, apart from icloud? I will try your suggestion!

Comment: It could be another cloud service like Dropbox or Google Drive. There are also online Backups that upload as soon as they connect to the internet (like Backblaze or Crashplan).

Answer (score 1):

Activity monitor and Little Snitch are good places to start.

With some aggravation, you can set up Wireshark which is an GUI interface to tcpdump.

A better option for this sort of thing is to repurpose an old laptop that has 2 ethernet ports, and set it up as a general network tool.  In one mode, you set it up as a bridge.  It doesn't have an ip address of it's own, but merely copies the packets that come through.

Turn off wifi on the suspect macbook, and connect it by cable to your network tool.  Now you can see the traffic going back and forth.